# Cisco Anyconnect vs network-manager-openconnect-gnome settings?

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, vpn

I currently have and use the official Cisco AnyConnect Client.

When I connect to it *all* it asks me for is my username and password.

When I try to connect to the same server using the package from `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` it looks like this:

[image: Add VPN dialog]

- Why are there so many options (Certificate, proxy etc.)?
- Why can't I connect with only a username and password like on the official client?

With the AnyConnect client all I need is the username and password.  I do not even have a cert for this VPN.

- How can I simplify this?

**Update:** The `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` looks better (i.e. fewer options) but it still asks for options I do not have (group name and group password):
[image]

The official client is so much simpler.

Comment: You can try `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` for comparison. It does not require certificate, but allows to connect to Cisco VPN.

Comment: @N0rbert this looks better (fewer options) but I still can't add the VPN until I enter a "group name" which again the official Anyconnect client does not ask for (and I do not have it).

Comment: try this: sudo apt install openconnect network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the openconnect network manager integration, all you really need is the gateway address - you also need that when you use the Cisco client. You can leave all other options at their defaults. When you connect, it'll ask for your username and password. (Tested on 18.10)

Comment: Thank you. I had a similar setting with NetworkManager on kde, openconnect plugin, on Centos 7. Just input the gateway address and then I was able to connect with user and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate to type the parameters that CiscoAnyconnect can show the user to enter if you use the console using a shell script and change also the proxy settings on the fly:

---

```
nmcli --ask con up id VPN_ConnectionName <<"EOF"
2
yourusername
yourpassword
EOF

echo "Now changing proxy to : yourproxyserver.com:8080"

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication true
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user 'yourusername'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password 'yourpassword'


gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'yourproxyserver.com'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host 'yourproxyserver.com'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host 'yourproxyserver.com
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host 'yourproxyserver.com'

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost',  '127.0.0.1','127.0.0.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect and reset proxy settings, run the following commands:

```
mcli  con down VPN_ConnectionName
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
```